# "mouseDown" event does not triggered on "click" In Mapbox-gl in a scenario

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Good day,

In mapbox gl js latest version, I bind a couple of events like click, mousedown, mouseup and mousemove.

In mobile device, if I click, the following order of event should occur:

```
"mouseMove"(First)
"mouseDown"
"mouseUp"
"click"(Last)
```

However, in some case's only mouseMove event is occurring. I noticed that this happens only when mapboxgl popup is added on Map and my mouse cursor is above it.

It seems like in mobile when I click on the marker, firstly "mouseMove" event gets called, which shows the popup. but then the rest of the events("mouseDown", "mouseUp" and "click") gets called on popup instead and not the map.

I am confused, How can I call the callbacks that are bind on Map(MapEvents) directly?

The one hack I can do is to add setTimeout delay, so that event could go down to map first and then add popup. But I really hope, if there could be a better way of achieving this.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Codepen(Request to please open in chrome mobile device emulator)

```
https://codepen.io/dollysingh3192/pen/QWKzdbO
```

Also, added a giphy at Dropbox(Edit with offset). Have a look!

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/87bq7t762s6t6qw/Jan-17-2021%2000-13-36.mp4?dl=0
```

Comment: I have tried your pen (and also taken the code to run separately) on Chrome, Edge and Firefox on Windows 10 looking at the dev tools console and I do not see the same problem as you - all the clicks give the full sequence, whether or not a popup is showing.

Comment: Hey @AHaworth, Thanks for your response, I have changed the code a little bit by adding the offset in mapbox gl popup(for replicating the issue easily.) I also added a new .mp4 video at dropbox. Please have a look

Comment: Hi, I don't really see what the error is. You have elected to have some events - including click - to be only 'seen' when it happens in places but outside those places you still notice mousemove as you haven't restricted those events to just in places. If you do then you dont see anything to do with clicks outside the places. Alternatively, if you remove the places variable from the on calls for e.g. click you see the full sequence even when you click outside the places.

Comment: @AHaworth Agree, Now I have updated the code and bind the events directly to the map(and not the places specifically). So ideally now if I click anywhere on the map(Even on places). the order of events from mouseMove to click should occur. But even now also, sometimes when I click on the top side of the marker order of events doesn’t log. Please check I have updated the video on dropbox and notice the position of the click.

Comment: @AHaworth and Stackoverflow team, I have registered the same issue as a bug on Mapbox https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10305 and they accepted it. Meanwhile, if there could be an any better way to achieve my problem. Please suggest, it would be very helpful for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Dolly Does this only happen in mobile because I have tried it on chrome in mac and it seems to be working fine for me also compared my reproduction steps with video that you have shared on dropbox and both are same and I see all the events firing.

Comment: Correct @Pritesh Events Order doesn't trigger in mobile.